# if result exists then update and don't insert?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to tweak this code so that if the result already exists in the database then to update it instead and not insert?

Could someone please show me how i might do this. i am really new to mysql and php.

```
<?php

    require_once('includes/session.php');
    require_once('includes/functions.php');
    require('includes/_config/connection.php');

    session_start();

        confirm_logged_in();

        if (isset ($_GET['to'])) {
        $user_to_id = $_GET['to'];


    }


    if (!isset($_GET['to']))
        exit('No user specified.');

    $user_id = $_GET['to'];


    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ptb_likes WHERE liked_id ='".$user_to_id."' ");

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO ptb_likes (user_id, liked_id) VALUES (".$_SESSION['user_id'].", ".$user_to_id.")"); 





    if($result) 
    { 
    mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_likes SET user_id_has_liked='1' WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."") 
    or die(mysql_error());

    mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_likes SET likes='1' WHERE liked_id=\"$profile_id\"") 
    or die(mysql_error());

    header("Location: {$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']}");

    }
    ?>
```

Comment: what is  difference between  your [last](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14799814/reverse-mysql-function-instead-of-insert-delete-and-update-enum-from-1-to-0) question and this ?

Comment: I would recommend you to take a look at one of all the SQL tutorials out there. You will find the answer in a couple of minutes. I can tell you have not researched this at all.

Comment: You should change your mysql functions. See the red box at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php ? It's deprecated. You should switch to mysqli or pdo.

Answer (score 1):

You should try with one MySQL statment.

**ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**

See more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html